# Search query is working but the query result is case sensitive - how do I resolve this?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

The search query perfectly works, but the query result is case sensitive.

How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "the query is case sensitive"? Can you be more precise? Are you referring that your variable "search" must be upper or lower case?

Comment: you have to change this in your database..

Comment: the query doesn't ignore the case if the search same as in the table it works but when changing the case it doesn't display the same search that previously displays.

Comment: Please copy paste your code directly and avoid posting screenshots of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to apply `LOWER` function on the query and, at the Java side, convert the variable `search` to lower case as well.
Your code should look like as follow:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from product where LOWER(name) like '%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%' or LOWER(category) like '%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%' and active='yes'");
```

However, for a matter of performances, I recommend that you create an index over the fields "name" and "category", if it's not already a composite key of the table "product".

Moreover, be careful of a possible `NullPointerException` which the statement `search.toLowerCase()` can cause.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply **Lower Function** on the query Definitely, you will get a positive result